# How to I set a robot pose in stage

Tags: ros, simulation, pose, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

is it possible to set the pose [x,y, alpha] of the simulated robot in stage via ROS?

Greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29562/how-to-i-set-a-robot-pose-in-stage/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2012-03-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2012-03-13**:
I would like to set the robots pose while the simulator is running. Any ideas?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-03-13**:
@Markus Bader Have a look, http://answers.ros.org/question/12384/change-simulator-stage-model-configurations-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you talking about setting the initial position?
You can set this by modifying your .world file. Example:

roomba( pose [ 3.2 8 0 0 ] name "roomba_0" color "red")

where roomba is the name of the model of my robot. The first argument of pose is the x position, the second is y position, third z position and the last is the orientation of the robot.

Another way to set the robot's position is to click on it and drag to the desired position.

---

Originally posted by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) with karma: 497 on 2012-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2012-03-13**:
Hello Lucas I would like to set the robots pose while the simulator is running.

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2012-03-13**:
Hello Lucas

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2012-03-13**:
If you want to set the robot's position while the simulator is running, you can click on the robot and drag it to the position that you want.

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2012-05-21**:
Hello and thanks for your comments. But I like to set and change the pose of the robot while the simulation is running. I have to run tests and I do not want to place the robot always with the mouse.
Greetings and thanks again

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-04-24**:
Hello,did you find a solution to this? can you share it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In agreement with [lucascoelho](http://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/), I cite an example. If you check out this tutorial, http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/IntroductiontoStageControllers and have a look at the *roomba-wander.world file*, then

> pose [ -8 6 0 0 ]

is the pose [x y z alpha] that you are looking for; x = -8, y = 6, z = 0 and alpha = 0.

Once the simulation has started, you can see the realtime pose, by clicking on the robot.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2012-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2012-03-13**:
Hello Arkapravo, I would like to set the robots pose while the simulator is running. Any ideas?